# Obtener Ultimo ID con filtro

Tags: sql-server

tengo este código para obtener el ultimo id de mi tabla `oper` pero únicamente de aquellos registros que contengan en su columna identificador el valor '1', el procedimiento no me devuelve nada, alguien me podría decir donde tengo el error:

```
-- Procedimiento Mostrar Ultimo Alumno
ALTER proc [dbo].[spmostrar_ultimo_alumno]
as
SELECT oper.idoper,oper.idcentro,oper.identificador,oper.codigo,oper.clasificacion,oper.denominacion,oper.direccion,oper.telefono,oper.email,oper.numero_doc,oper.url,oper.contacto,oper.estado FROM oper  
where oper.idoper = (SELECT MAX(oper.idoper) FROM oper) and oper.identificador='1'
```

muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Esto es básicamente lo que haces:

```
SELECT *
       FROM oper
       where oper.idoper = (SELECT MAX(oper.idoper) FROM oper) 
             and oper.identificador='1'
```

Que representa, obtener aquella fila con el máximo `idoper` de toda la tabla y que además `identificador = '1'`, seguramente esas dos condiciones no se dan simultáneamente, por eso no obtienes resultados

Lo que debieras hacer es algo así:

```
SELECT *
       FROM oper
       where oper.idoper = (SELECT MAX(oper.idoper) 
                                   FROM oper
                                   oper.identificador='1' )
```